# Website and Mobile Application Database Linking

Tags: android, ios, database, web, web-deployment

I have an idea for a website that will require the use of a database to keep track of user accounts, and other things the user does on the website. I have experience with developing websites with MySQL database. I was hoping to also create an application for the website on Android and iOS. I have some experience with Android development, and I am still learning quite a lot. However, I have not done anything with databases in mobile devices.

What would be the best way to create a mobile applications and a website that the user could use to access their accounts. Would it be best to have a mobile database on the handset and sync it with the database on the server, or would it be best to have the application query the database on the server directly?

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: have the database on the cloud and sync your phone to the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I suggest is to use APIs.

You can create APIs to access the database through your mobile application.

You website will also be using the same database, and your mobile application will be calling the APIs to get data from the database.

May be this can help you to get started: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/10/android-full-app-part-2-using-http-api.html

Answer (score 1):

I think, Use web-service to communicate with web database. It is easy to use because you are using this database for both android and ios.

Thanks.